# Different results when running linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux and trying to understand.....

I have got a software package for CentOs7 which I need to install (according to the manual) by calling `./install.sh` **which is in my current directory**, when doing so everything works OK.

AFAIK, in Linux `./` means current directory, so why am I getting `install.sh: Command not found` when just calling `install.sh` (i.e. without `./`) from the **current directory**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, UNIX and related operating systems, `.` denotes the current directory. Since you want to run a file in your current directory

you need the `./` bit to tell the shell where the executable is.

So, `./install.sh` means run the executable called `install.sh` that is in this directory.

PS: If your current dictionary is registered in $PATH, you don't need to use `./install.sh` just `install.sh` is enough

Comment: Just to mention, if you are tempted, that adding `.` to your path is considered a security risk: It is relatively easy for an attacker to put a malicious program called `ls` or `echo` in your current folder, and this would cause chaos. So on unix we live with having to explicitly put `./` to run from the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just call `install.sh` or any other script with ./ then the same should be in the bin folder. If the script is in any other directory, then `./` is must.